# Hide AppBar menu on desktop (large width screens)

Tags: angular2-mdl

I want to show/hide the menu icon (the 3 horizontal bars below) in the AppBar depending on the width of the screen. Is there a directive or a css class that makes this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding class "mdl-layout--small-screen-only" to the div containing the md-icon in mdl-layout.component.js.